# Is there a possibility to set a Channel Icon

Tags: mattermost

I was wondering whether it is possible to define a costume mattermost channel item. In our team we have several channel and some of them are more important then others, so a costume icon would stick out.

Comment: Mattermost doesn't yet has this feature, but you can add an emoji before the channel name to give a visual indicator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mattermost doesn't yet has this feature, but you can add an emoji before the channel name to give a visual indicator.